Does the operating system used to create a GPG key get stored with the key?
I generated a new GPG key for personal use using the gpg --full-generate-key command on FreeBSD. Is the name of the operating system where the key was created stored in the key itself? Can I use this key on a Debian machine as if it were created on Debian?

The key itself is just random numbers.
Yes, GPG uses the same file format on different platforms, so you can exchange keys.

So if I create the key on FreeBSD today but decide to switch back to Linux next week, does it still not matter that the key was created on FreeBSD?

It does not matter.
